# Credentials cannot be used for NTLM authentication

Tags: java

I am getting

> org.apache.commons.httpclient.auth.InvalidCredentialsException:
> Credentials cannot be used for NTLM authentication:

exception in eclipse

Whether it is possible mention eclipse to take system proxy settings directly?

```
public class HttpGetProxy {
    private static final String PROXY_HOST = "proxy.****.com";
    private static final int PROXY_PORT = 6050;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        HttpMethod method = new GetMethod("https://kodejava.org");

        HostConfiguration config = client.getHostConfiguration();
        config.setProxy(PROXY_HOST, PROXY_PORT);

        String username = "*****";
        String password = "*****";
        Credentials credentials = new UsernamePasswordCredentials(username, password);
        AuthScope authScope = new AuthScope(PROXY_HOST, PROXY_PORT);

        client.getState().setProxyCredentials(authScope, credentials);

        try {
            client.executeMethod(method);

            if (method.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
                String response = method.getResponseBodyAsString();
                System.out.println("Response = " + response);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            method.releaseConnection();
        }
    }
}
```

Exception:

> Dec 08, 2017 1:41:39 PM
> org.apache.commons.httpclient.auth.AuthChallengeProcessor selectAuthScheme
> INFO: ntlm authentication scheme selected
> Dec 08, 2017 1:41:39 PM org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector executeConnect
> SEVERE: Credentials cannot be used for NTLM authentication:
> org.apache.commons.httpclient.UsernamePasswordCredentials
> org.apache.commons.httpclient.auth.InvalidCredentialsException: Credentials
> cannot be used for NTLM authentication:
> `enter code here`
> org.apache.commons.httpclient.UsernamePasswordCredentials
> at org.apache.commons.httpclient.auth.NTLMScheme.authenticate(NTLMScheme.java:332)
> at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.authenticateProxy(HttpMethodDirector.java:320)
> at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeConnect(HttpMethodDirector.java:491)
> at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:391)
> at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171)
> at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
> at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:323)
> at HttpGetProxy.main(HttpGetProxy.java:31)
> Dec 08, 2017 1:41:39 PM org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector processProxyAuthChallenge
> INFO: Failure authenticating with NTLM @proxy.****.com:6050

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/authentication.html) the following authentication schemes are supported: Basic,Digest,NTLM,SPNEGO,Kerberos

In particular:

> NTLM:  NTLM is a proprietary authentication scheme developed by
>   Microsoft and optimized for Windows platforms. NTLM is believed to be
>   more secure than Digest.

So in order to avoid this warning use the following CredentialProvider:

```
CredentialsProvider provider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
provider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, new NTCredentials("user", "pwd", "", "domain"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use credentials in the form of domain\username in the "username" field, for NTLM authentication to work properly.

Comment: Still it is not working. I have added the domain and checked it not working

Comment: @bharathi There is even some configuration in Windows Server if BasicAuthentication can be used as fallback for NTLM (I am not sure if it is enabled by default). If would simplify your life very much if this option is enabled. Otherwise you will have to write your own [AuthScheme](http://devsac.blogspot.be/2010/10/supoprt-for-ntlmv2-with-apache.html)

Comment: @bharathi Have you been able to resolve the issue, if so what is the fix for it ?